# An exotic problem happens when the entity framework gets installed by NuGet

Tags: entity-framework, nuget

I just simply want to install Entity-Framework 6.3.0, but an exotic exception is thrown by NuGet package manager. it says :

> Install-Package : The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add 
>   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 
>   format.

I haven't seen such an exception before, and don't have any idea what it exactly means.

I use

> Visual studio 2013
>   .Net Framework 4.5

I have already tried to resolve the issue. Nonetheless, it didn't work out. Actually, I tried to follow the exception's instruction and add the mentioned attribute into the project tag. It was not useful at all!

Let me tell you that I have actually created a repository on GitHub, cloned the repository, and finally created this project inside it.  I don't know if this process is relevant to the problem, though I think you should know that.

I will be glad if you guys tell me what the problem is and how I can resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48419496/6311045).

Comment: @MasLoo I've already read that. they are not related. The scenarios are totally different.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49107996/6311045) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42509354/6311045) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32585447/6311045)?

Comment: @MasLoo. Sure. I've read all of them. All of those topics are talking about .Net Core projects and its new related csproj files which cannot be processed by older versions of visual studio. Considering the fact that I didn't use .Net Core, and I created the original project using vs2013, it shouldn't show me such an error. My problem is that NuGet returns this exception while it is installing the EntityFramework!

Comment: @Masloo. I checked the project's csproj file. It seemed a little odd and different from other csproj files that I've ever seen in my life. Although it may sound ridiculous, I've decided to change the csproj myself. I don't know what the consequences will be, though I am going take the chance.

Comment: @MasLoo. I am also thinking about downgrading the version of EntityFramework. I have not had this problem with EntityFramework 6.2.0.

Comment: It's not odd to change csproj file manually, but consider to take a copy of it before any changes. If you didn't had this issue with EF 6.2.0 it's possible that the version you're using is a pre-release version and it's not stable, you can fix it with upgrading it or as you said downgrade it.

Comment: @MasLoo. You should know that I've always admired Persian answers. Always! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply downgraded Entity Framework to the **6.2.0** and the problem was solved! Although NuGet introduces **6.3.0** as a stable version of the EF, it seems that the version has a huge problem with either VS2013 or .Net 4.5

Comment: @Malsoo. Check my answer, if you are interested.

Comment: I cannot do this since the new System.Data.SQLite.* v. 1.0.112 requires 6.3 (and 1.0.111 was *removed* already and is not available in VS NuGet manager!)
We had to put 111 in our local NuGet feed server and force fixed version numbers of all these packages for our nuget restore to work!

Comment: This does not solve the issue you posted, it only avoids it.  It is not an answer.

Comment: I get the same problem when I try to deploy to Azure. Downgrading is the only way to get the site to deploy. Not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

EF 6.3 requires MSBuild version 15 which ships with Visual Studio 2017.  That appears to be your issue.  You may be stuck on version 6.2 until you upgrade.